# static variables in deserialization?

Tags: java, variables, serialization, static, deserialization

I study from various documents and books but i am not getting understand that if static variables does not participate in serialization, how it is loaded in deserialization. I did the following program:
(Thanks in advance).

```
 public class SerializationDemo {
        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {

        ObjectOutputStream o=new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("d:\\test.txt"));
        Test ob=new Test();
        Test ob1=new Test();
        ob1.add();
        o.writeObject(ob);//serialize obj
        o.flush();
        System.out.println("success Written");

        //Deserialization

        ObjectInputStream in=new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("d:\\test.txt"));
        Test a=(Test)in.readObject();

        **System.out.println(a.a+" "+a.b);//output :7 9**
        }
    }
    class Test implements Serializable{
        int a;
        static int b;
        public Test(){
            a=7;

        }
         void add(){
            b=9;
        }
    }
```

Comment: What did you expect it to print? Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your test proves nothing.

If you want to observe it, you need to:

1. Set `Test.b` to some value X.
2. Serialize the `Test` object.
3. Set `Test.b` to a different value Y.
4. De-serialize.

You will observe that `Test.b` still has the value `Y`, which it wouldn't have if `Test.b` had been serialized and de-serialized.